# Spring translate java.sql.SQLException to DataAccessException

Tags: spring, exception, translate

Hallo.
Since it seems that I cannot use the spring DataAccessException translation mechanism in my dao, I would like to know if it possible to translate the

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: [BEA][Oracle JDBC Driver][Oracle]ORA-00001: unique constraint (JSP_OWN.IDX_MC_CC_RAPPORTI_02) violated
```

to the DataAccessException hierarchy manually.

Kind regards
Massimo

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `JdbcTemplate`, you can do

```
catch (SqlException e) {
  throw jdbcTemplate.getExceptionTranslator().translate("my task", null, e);
}
```

If you do not have `JdbcTemplate`, just look at the source code of the `JdbcTemplate.getExceptionTranslator()` method:

```
public synchronized SQLExceptionTranslator getExceptionTranslator() {
    if (this.exceptionTranslator == null) {
        DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
        if (dataSource != null) {
            this.exceptionTranslator = new SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator(dataSource);
        }
        else {
            this.exceptionTranslator = new SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator();
        }
    }
    return this.exceptionTranslator;
}
```

And mimic it's behaviour :-)